# Road network data for Pakistan

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am trying to make a detailed map of roads in Pakistan road. I have already used sources like OSM, DivaGIS, but they don't give me enough detail (amount of point, polyline and polygon features).

Can anyone guide me to more accurate data?
Can we download the road network of Google Maps maybe?
Even any kind of script to scrape data would do the trick.

Comment: This question needs more info. Please [read this](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) and [edit] your question. What *details*? What resolution? Costs? If you *have already used the other sources of data like OSM, DivaGIS*, then how/why did those not work?

Comment: Dear @JanDoggen, they have worked just fine but i need more detail into my map, as much as possible in terms of point, polyline and polygon features

Comment: I have edited your question to make that clearer, but to make it a good question you would have to edit it more and be *exact*: what resolution can you achieve with the datasets you have now, and what resolution would you like to have? You also have not answered the question about costs, [edit] that in please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook's MapWithAI initiative builds off of existing OSM data. I cannot speak to the quality of the data, but you can find the data and information on how to download it [here](https://github.com/facebookmicrosites/Open-Mapping-At-Facebook/wiki/Available-Countries).

Answer (score 1):

Generally road network data are represented by polyline geometries. I would not expect to find point or polygon data from the sources that you have mentioned.